# Issue installing Squid

Tags: squid

When I install Squid using `sudo apt-get install squid` this message came:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package squid is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'squid' has no installation candidate
```

I try to upgrade after 55% it failed:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu uses squid3 instead of just plain squid.

```
sudo apt-get install squid3
```